# Creating a ListIterator object

Tags: java, interface

If ListIterator is an interface how come I can create a ListIterator Object like below?

```
LinkedList<String> myList = new LinkedList<String>();

ListIterator<String> iter = myList.listIterator();
```

Comment: `listIterator()` is a *method* which internally creates and returns instance of class which implements ListIterator. So that instance is of ListIterator *type*, but not class.

Comment: The object created here is of the class which implements `ListIterator` and stored in memory. `iter` is storing the reference to that `object` only.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the implementation of `java.util.LinkedList` in Java 8 you will see that it contains this `listIterator()` implementation:

```
public ListIterator<E> listIterator(int index) {
    checkPositionIndex(index);
    return new ListItr(index);
}
```

Effectively what is returned is an instance of an internal class `ListItr` which implements the `ListIterator` interface. The client has to interact with this instance of `ListItr` using the `ListIterator` interface after calling the `listIterator()` method.

Comment: Thank you I did not know this fact and it explains it better

Comment: You are welcome. In case this answer or the other answer answered your question you can consider to accept one of them.

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot create Objects of Interfaces.**

> **`myList.listIterator();` returns an object of `ListItr` class**, not an object of `ListIterator<E>` interface.

```
private class ListItr extends Itr implements ListIterator<E>{...}
```

As the `ListItr` class implements `ListIterator<E>`, you can reference the returned the object from `ListIterator<E>`.

Comment: Thank you. I understand a bit better now. Also I see that I can have a reference var of type interface from this answer